# BadMethodCallException, method getLogin doesn't exists l

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.4

I'm working on authentication and using the following code in routes.

Authentication routes:

```
Route::get('auth/login',['uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@getLogin']);
Route::post('auth/login',['uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@postLogin']);
Route::get('auth/logout',['uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@getLogout']);
```

I'm facing the following problem when I type in 'localhost:8000/auth/login':

> BadMethodCallException
>   Method [getLogin] does not exist.`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller{


 use AuthenticatesUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
 protected $redirectTo = '/';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}
```

}
`

How to solve this problem and where is `getLogin` method?

I'm using `laravel` 5.4.

Comment: Could you also post the code of your LoginController?

Comment: yes gladly,I'v added the code,you can see in the post @Sven Hakvoort

Comment: You will have to create the `getLogin` function in your controller yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try with, it seem like method name is `showLoginForm`

```
Route::get('login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm']);
Route::post('login', ['as' => 'login.post', 'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@login']);
Route::post('logout', ['as' => 'logout', 'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@logout']);
```

Or you can directly use `auth` method in router, it registered all the auth routes
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L1007